# Consulta en sql server con tabla con @

Tags: sql-server

Soy algo nuevo en Sql Server, quisiera saber como realizar una consulta por medio de sql server a una tabla que tiene un arroba (no la cree así) fue establecida por el programa Sap.
Mi tabla es más o menos así:

```
select * from @PRE_COBRANZA
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando una columna o una tabla contiene **caracteres especiales**, **palabras reservadas** o bien **espacios**, se rodea el nombre del objeto con conchetes.

Así en tu caso debería funcionarte

```
select * from [@PRE_COBRANZA]
```

Comment: Gracias, funcionó :D

Comment: ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, @user9509702? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!